# nodemon or nodemon index.js not working on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules, nodemon

I am trying to run my server automatically after every push, do not want to restart every time on ubuntu instance 16.04

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor/run.js:356
    let sig = signal.replace('SIG', '');
    ^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor/index.js:2:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
```

having this error, can anyone tell what is the problem?

Comment: What is the nodejs version you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks budy @developerKumar and sorry for late reply.
you gave me a hint I simply upgrade my node version and its working.